# AWS S3 data format for clickstream analysis

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3, hive

We are using Kafka queue for collecting clickstream data, in json format, from different devices.We need to analyze this data via Hive (or maybe Spark). We consider using hourly partitions and we will call our hive/spark job in every hour. 
I read information about different file formats but I could not decide the optimal file format for a better query performance. We tried to hold json data in avro format in s3 but queries are slow.

We may insert json data into s3 as a columnar format. (instead if inserting one column which holds the entire json record) What do you think over holding each json attribute in a different column in s3? (our schema is changing very rarely)

We will run hourly hive/spark jobs. so we need to retrieve all records in a hourly partition. however I will query different columns in different queries. Which file format is better for our case? (avro, parquet,orc,etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, Hive nor Spark are exactly fast on S3 data. Presto/Athena would be faster purely on adhoc SQL queries over S3. Keep in mind, if you are using these options, you need a way to update the Hive metastore... simply landing files into a new hourly file path in S3 is not enough.

ORC or Parquet are far more performant than Avro. Avro is more performant than JSON or plain text (plus accommodates schema evolution). [Netflix has done performance testing on ORC and Parquet on S3 using Presto](https://medium.com/netflix-techblog/using-presto-in-our-big-data-platform-on-aws-938035909fd4)

Not sure what you mean by "We tried to hold json data in avro format"... If you are using [Kafka S3 Connector by Confluent](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-storage-cloud/kafka-connect-s3/docs/s3_connector.html), and used a converter, then it doesn't not offer Hive integration at this time. But if you somehow added Hive to it, and you're getting slow queries, then you need to increase the flush size of your files. It also doesn't support useful query  formats other than JSON or Avro.

If you're using [Secor by Pinterest](https://github.com/pinterest/secor), that offers Parquet & ORC support from Kafka, and Hive integration so I would recommend it.

If you want to process hourly records in a streaming framework rather than batches, you can use those too, and would be faster than waiting for S3 results.

Comment: Thank you
I mean:
Clients are sending data in json format.
So I have two options:
1-) parsing data in Kafka(via ksql etc) and inserting records into Amazon s3 in csv format. I will create an external table in hive and scan hourly partition.
2-) I will insert records into Amazon s3 in json format. So I will also need to parse json format in hive layer.

So we need to decide where we should parse json in kafka or in s3 via hive

Comment: No, avoid CSV entirely at all costs. Convert the JSON to Avro before ever touching S3 or Hive. KSQL can do it, but Kafka Streams would have more programming flexibility as KSQL is still not fully feature complete with Avro compatibility.

Comment: I am calculating video viewership durations and doing path analysis so I need to correlate records by using analytical functions ( lead,lag ) I need to analyze all records in a session. If the customer is watching a long movie (for ex. the lord of the rings), one session may last 3 or 4 hours. So kafka streams or spark streams may not be enough. (I need to join streaming data with the batch data in s3)

Comment: From what I understand, you are not getting JSON every few hours, rather more frequently. You can use kafka streams to convert JSON records to Avro on a separate topic at each record, which is what KSQL would do internally anyway. Or you can just use Kafka Connect's AvroConverter to take the JSON data to Avro automatically for you and write to S3.

Comment: thank you.so we can query avro formatted table without using json functions?

Comment: Yes. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AvroSerDe Or you can dump JSON messages to Parquet using Secor - https://github.com/pinterest/secor